# Print out rows taken from query

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I know there are a lot of similar question but i can't understand how it works.
My problem is that i have started my first project (also my first coding adventure) with php using mysql without prepared statements, using mysql non-prepared statements everything it's ok my problem came out when i stated to write the project from scratch with prepared statements.
I have read a lot of tutorials manuals but i'm not really good in english and i cant undestand how to make this:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT (filename,ext) FROM userpic WHERE username= ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
```

There are hundreds of rows and i have to create a cicle that takes out filename and ext
and prints me out the path for the image but how does it work to take out the array with filename and ext and create the cicle for every row.

i cant understand how it works in non prepared statements i used for example this:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT filename FROM users WHERE username = '$_SESSION[username]' ")or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo "<img id=\"membimagestyle\" src=\"uploads/$row[filename]\"></div>";
}
```

i cant understand how to use mysql_fetch_array , $row[filename] in prepared statement version.

Thanks for everyone helping me!!
&
Sorry for my bad coding skills and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: why are you not using mysqli (instead of mysql)??

Comment: the second piece of code was the old source and i was using mysql now my problem is that i dont know how to create the cicle to print out the array of every row on mysqli.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I hope this example will help you solve you problem

```
$query = "SELECT filename FROM users WHERE username = ?";


if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
   // bind parameter
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $username);

  // execute
   $stmt->execute();

   // bind result to a variable
   $stmt->bind_result($filename);

   // iterate through the results
   while ($stmt->fetch()) {        
        echo "<img id=\"membimagestyle\" src=\"uploads/$filename\"></div>";
    }    

    // close the statement   
    $stmt->close();
}
```

EDIT:
If you want to fetch multiple columns do the following:

```
$stmt->bind_result($filename, $extension);

while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    echo "<img id=\"membimagestyle\" src=\"uploads/$filename.$extension\"></div>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks this is what i needed a clear example with comments only one question now it's clear.

Only one question if the query selects 2 or 3 fields how does the bind to result works??

Example query

SELECT filename name extension FROM users WHERE username = ?
How to bind to a usable variable also name and extension?

Thanks a lot

Comment: i really don't know why the down vote i have no reputation points to give you a positive feedback and i didn't give you the negative vote your answere is perfect for my case and i really thank you Stefan E for your help